# Laravel check status and send email

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have table with events. 
In table events I have column status with:

1) 0 - waiting 
2) 1 - accepted

And column: date_start.

I need check all responses where status = 0 and send email 30 days before the start event.

Example:
I have event: 
 
1) name street Event 
2) status = 0; 
3) date_start = 22.06.2018

I need send email when day will be: 22.05.2018 that is tomorrow.

I created mail:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NotifyApplication extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.notify');
    }
 }
```

And I created job (NotifyJob):

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\User;
use Mail;

class NotifyMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
                $users = User::all();
                $events = Events::all();
                foreach($users as $user) {
                   Mail::to($request->user())->send(new NotifyApplication());
                }
     }
}
```

What I need do, that my task was realized. I need cron?

Comment: Yea. You need cron to do that. You need to create a Laravel command that check what emails that should send at the day and then dispatch the` NotifyJob` . This laravel command will run via cron. You can set it what time it will running.